# incorrect number of dimensions error when I did the loop with matrices list

Tags: r, list

I got the error message when I tried to pass a list of matrices to a newly defined list.

```
t<-list()
for(i in 1:N){t[[i]]<-Z[[i]][,2]}
```

here Z is a list of matrices with different sizes(the number of columns in each matrix is same but the rows of matrix is different. And I attempted to create a new matrices list t and each matrix in t has the second column of corresponding matrix in original list Z. But it always didn't work.
The most strange thing is N is 300 but this loop stopped when N approached to 81 every time and gave the error message. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Instead of this try `lapply(Z, "[", , 2)`

Comment: @lei Can you tell us the dim of `dim(Z[[82]])`

Comment: Yeah, I guess that is the problem. Because I only have one line in  Z[[82]] which is not a matrix here.